# RESTful web service using Spring Data REST is not working but RESTful web service using Spring MVC is working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

PostRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import com.example.demo.domain.Post;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import java.util.List;

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "posts", path = "posts")
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {
        Post findOneByTitle(@Param("title") String title);
        List<Post> findByBodyContaining(@Param("keyword") String keyword);
        }
```

PostRestController.java

```
package com.example.demo.web;

import com.example.demo.domain.Post;
import com.example.demo.repository.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
@RestController
public class PostRestController {
    @Autowired
    private final PostRepository postRepository;
    public PostRestController(PostRepository postRepository) {
            this.postRepository = postRepository;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post/findByTitle")
    public Post findOneByTitle(@RequestParam("title") String title) {
            return postRepository.findOneByTitle(title);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post/search")
    public List<Post> findByBodyContaining(@RequestParam("keyword") String keyword) {
            return postRepository.findByBodyContaining(keyword);
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/post/count")
    public long count() {
            return postRepository.count();
    }
}
```

All of the below are working

```
 http://localhost:8080/ 
 http://localhost:8080/h2-console 
 http://localhost:8080/post/search?keyword=Geeky
 http://localhost:8080/post/findByTitle?title=Youtube
```

But http://localhost:8080/posts is not working (404 error)

I just wanted to learn spring and I know should follow recent guides, but started this one and I've been sitting with this for 3 days, first was javax to jakarta name change that caused huge problem and then this one where `@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "posts", path = "posts")` seems to be not working, have been looking into solutions for the past 3 hours but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, you could consider either removing the @RepositoryRestResource annotation from the PostRepository or changing the path in the @RequestMapping annotation for the findByTitle method in PostRestController. Make sure there's no conflicting mapping that could be causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So I tried removing the RepositoryRestResource annotation but didn't work. Then changed all paths of RequestMapping annotation but then too http://localhost:8080/posts is not working (404 error)